# How to convert sort using cmp from python 2 to python 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sorting

I'm trying to convert this code which is written in python 2 to python 3

```
nums = ["30", "31"]
num.sort(cmp=lambda x, y: cmp(y + x, x + y))
```

Not sure how to do that in python 3 since cmp is removed (I believed)

The result should be `["31", "30"]` instead of `["30", "31"]`

Comment: @Pythonista: This isn't sorting in reverse order. It's a lot subtler than that, and converting the comparator to a key function is actually pretty tricky.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key

Comment: Can you provide test data which fails with `sort(reverse=True)`?

Comment: @PeterWood: `["3", "31"]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043067/python3-style-sorting-old-cmp-method-functionality-in-new-key-mechanism/47529463#47529463 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python3 style sorting -- old cmp method functionality in new key mechanism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043067/python3-style-sorting-old-cmp-method-functionality-in-new-key-mechanism)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is one of the rare cases where a comparator is much cleaner than a key function. I'd actually just reimplement `cmp`:

```
try:
    cmp
except NameError:
    def cmp(x, y):
        if x < y:
            return -1
        elif x > y:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

and then use [`functools.cmp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) to convert the comparator to a Python 3 style key function:

```
nums.sort(key=functools.cmp_to_key(lambda x, y: cmp(y+x, x+y)))
```

For anyone wondering what this weird sort actually does, it finds the order in which to concatenate the input strings to produce the lexicographically greatest output string. When all the strings are sequences of digits, the output has the highest possible numeric value.

Comment: Or `def cmp(x, y): return (x > y) - (x < y)`

Comment: One remark: python2 `cmp` function can compare `None` with other value, `cmp(1, None) == 1`, `cmp(None, None) == 0`, `cmp(None, 1) == -1`. But python3 `>` comparation doesn't accept None: `1 > None`: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'`. So to make your answer more details, I'd add `None` comparation `if` branches to custom `cmp` function.

Comment: @Kirill: Python 2 would try to produce an output for comparing just about anything with anything. It wasn't something particular to `cmp` or `None`, and it's not something we need to replicate for this task.